# Why does mobile nav button expand on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile nav button that upon touching/clicking, should expand and reveal page links. Problem is when you first start the page the button is already expanded:

[image]

But should actually load page with elements hidden like so:

[image]

The X icon and Line-stack Icon are also reversed. How would I switch these icons around and also make sure the page loads with them closed? I tried switching the icons classes in the jQuery function to switch the x and line-stack but that hasn't worked.

I know there is a simple concept I am missing but I am quite new to jQuery and am having trouble here.

My HTML:

```
                 <nav>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="img/logoblack.png" alt="logo" class="logo img-fluid">
                        <img src="img/logoblack.png" alt="logo" class="logo-black">
                        <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Skill</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Résumé</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

My CSS:

```
.mobile-nav-icon {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer; /* Used since no href tag specifying link type */
    display: none;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.js--nav-icon').click(function() {
    var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
    var icon = $('.js--nav-icon i');

    nav.slideToggle(200);
    if (icon.hasClass('ion-navicon-round')) {
        icon.addClass('ion-close-round');
        icon.removeClass('ion-navicon-round');
    } else {
        icon.addClass('ion-navicon-round');
        icon.removeClass('ion-close-round');
    }

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you likely haven't provided enough of the CSS to allow others to help answer this question. I'm *assuming* that the error is because you are hiding `.mobile-nav-icon` instead of `.main-nav`. Perhaps you meant to use the `.main-nav` CSS selector instead? Have you confirmed that you have a `display: none` in a CSS class for `.main-nav`? If that was not a simple oversight, please update your question so that it shows *all* relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ObsidianAge that was it! I didn't have the .main-nav on display:none! I did this on a media query for small width screens and now it works perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem; glad you figured it out eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to create a media query that would hide the .main-nav with display-none;. This way the

tags were hidden on mobile devices but still shows in a navbar on a browser:

```
/* Small phones to small tablets from: 481px to 767px*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .main-nav {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-left: 25px;
        display: none;
    }

}
```